# Summary band with Page Footer only

Tags: jasper-reports, summary

I have one report in which I want to show page footer but don't want to show page header portion - In Summary band. I can either display both or none by checking **"Summary with Page Header and Footer"**

Answer (score 2):

IN this case I shifted all the matter of page header to column header as column header does not print in summary band. Its worked now no data in page header so its not printing in summary band and page footer gets printed. And also printing summary on new page.